# EF Identity column order

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am developing a MVC app with EF 6. I have a entity Complian which has a property ComplainID. I user code first migration to create the database. In database ComplainID column is a Identity column with identity increment is 1. In the development environment everything works fine.

How ever in the hosted application in IIS 7.5 with SQL server 2012 ComplianID column doesn't behave as it is expected. If a new complain is added after about 2-3 days ComplainID increment near to 1000.

Ex : Let say on friday i add 4 complains. Corrosponding ComplainID for those is 2003,2004.2005.2006. Then No complain was added on weekends. When a new complain is added on Monday instead of getting CompalinID as 2007 I'm getting a ComplainID of 3005.

I have no idea how these kind of bugs can be debug. There for can some one give me some insight how to solve this problem.

Comment: More than likely, ATTEMPTS to insert additional records in your table are failing (the identity will still be incremented), or alternatively, records are being inserted but then being deleted, or rolled back.

Comment: Actually my initial thought was the same. However I found from another forum that that due to caching in SQL server gaps between identity values are possible upon insertion.

More information on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx